# I'm using pyramid_sacrud and get the error "403 Forbidden Access was denied to this resource. Unauthorized: sa_home failed permission check"

Tags: pyramid

I follow the official docs, and set it step by step.
Using browser point to http://localhost:6543/sacrud/, here raise 403 Forbidden error. I'm trying to delete `sa_home` function's parameter permission in `pyramid_sacrud/views/init.py` to solve it, though It could be access but it hasn't login page in there.

Here is my app's ini file:

```python
from pyramid.config import Configurator
from sqlalchemy import engine_from_config
from pyramid.authentication import AuthTktAuthenticationPolicy
from pyramid.authorization import ACLAuthorizationPolicy
from pyramid.session import SignedCookieSessionFactory
from pyraid_blogr.models.models import BlogRecord, User

from .models.meta import (
    DBSession,
    Base,
)


def main(global_config, **settings):
    """ This function returns a Pyramid WSGI application.
    """
    engine = engine_from_config(settings, 'sqlalchemy.')
    DBSession.configure(bind=engine)
    Base.metadata.bind = engine
    authentication_policy = AuthTktAuthenticationPolicy('your_secret', hashalg='sha512')
    authorization_policy = ACLAuthorizationPolicy()
    config = Configurator(settings=settings,
                          authentication_policy=authentication_policy,
                          authorization_policy=authorization_policy
                          )
    config.set_session_factory(SignedCookieSessionFactory('replace_your_secret'))
    config.include('pyramid_mako',)
    config.include('pyramid_sacrud',)
    settings = config.registry.settings
    settings['pyramid_sacrud.models'] = (('Group1', [BlogRecord]), ('Group2', [User]))
    config.add_static_view('static', 'static', cache_max_age=3600)
    config.add_route('home', '/')
    config.add_route('blog', '/blog/{id:\d+}/{slug}', request_method='GET')
    config.add_route('blog_action', '/blog/{action}', factory='pyraid_blogr.security.BlogRecordFactory')
    config.add_route('auth', 'sign/{action}')
    config.scan()
    return config.make_wsgi_app()
```

---

Here is the debug info

> permission pyramid_sacrud_home value  'pyramid_sacrud_home' Source
>   Line 45 of file
>   /Users/liu-minglei/Web-Dev/my_pyramid/pyraid_blogr/admin/views/**init**.py:
>   permission=PYRAMID_SACRUD_HOME References view function
>   admin.views.sa_home

Comment: Please enabled `debug_authorization` to get more meaningful error message: http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid//en/latest/narr/security.html#debugging-view-authorization-failures

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa  ***here is debug info**                                           permission pyramid_sacrud_home
value 'pyramid_sacrud_home'
Source
Line 45 of file /Users/liu-minglei/Web-Dev/my_pyramid/pyraid_blogr/admin/views/__init__.py:
permission=PYRAMID_SACRUD_HOME
References
view function admin.views.sa_home

Comment: Can you please add the information to the question through it. It is very difficult to read in a comment due to formatting.

Comment: You are using sacrud and it is missing  some sacrud permission. Maybe you are configuring it incorrectly? Contact to sacrud authors for more help?

Answer (score 0):

I have created an example with authorization (https://github.com/ITCase/pyramid_sacrud/tree/master/example), in your case, you seem to have edit `pyramid_sacrud/views/init.py` file that is not location in your python env or not reload server. For your app you must add sacrud permission (http://pyramid-sacrud.readthedocs.org/en/latest/pages/permissions.html) to root_factory.